# Setting values to null in foreach loops?

Tags: php

I am working with a CSV file and I would like $row at the end of each foreach loop to end up looking like this:

```
[0] => 3712
[1] => FirstName
[2] => LastName
[4] => sample@string1.co
[5] => sample@string2.co
[6] => sample@string3.co
[7] => sample@string4.co

[0] => 3064
[1] => FirstName
[2] => LastName
[4] => sample@string1.co
[5] => null
[6] => null
[7] => null

[0] => 7651
[1] => FirstName
[2] => LastName
[4] => sample@string1.co
[5] => sample@string2.co
[6] => null
[7] => null


$emails = array(
array('PersonId' => 3712, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string1.co'), 
array('PersonId' => 3712, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string2.co'), 
array('PersonId' => 3712, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string3.co'), 
array('PersonId' => 3712, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string4.co'), 
array('PersonId' => 3064, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string1.co'),  
array('PersonId' => 7651, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string1.co'), 
array('PersonId' => 7651, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string2.co'),
array('PersonId' => 5431, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string1.co'), 
array('PersonId' => 5431, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string2.co'), 
array('PersonId' => 5431, 'EmailAddress' => 'sample@string3.co'));
```

CSV file looks like this:

```
2221 FirstName LastName
5431 FirstName LastName
9923 FirstName LastName
7651 FirstName LastName
3712 FirstName LastName
3064 FirstName LastName
8341 FirstName LastName
```

This is what I have right now, but I feel like I'm not even close to doing this right. I can't seem to figure out how to get the later values to be null based on the largest amount of emails. Is this even doable? Currently it's adding all the emails like it is supposed to, but it isn't adding the 8 total elements to each array.

```
while($row = fgetcsv($fp, ",")){
    $count = 3;
    foreach($emails as $email){  
        if($row[0] == $email['PersonId']){
            $row[$count] = $email['EmailAddress'];   
            $count++;
        } else{
            if(!isset($row[$count])){
                $row[$count] = ' ';
            }
        } 
    }
  print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Hi, where is `[3]` in your row?

Comment: I've marked my answer as deleted, because I think I've done it wrong. your CSV "sample" doesn't include any email addresses? is this correct? Is the [0] to [7] arrays your input or your desires output? is `$emails` input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close! Just pad the $row array with null values so that it's got 8 elements!

```
while($row = fgetcsv($fp, ",")){
    $count = 3;
    foreach($emails as $email){  
        if($row[0] == $email['PersonId']){
            $row[$count] = $email['EmailAddress'];   
            $count++;
        } else{
            if(!isset($row[$count])){
                $row[$count] = ' ';
            }
        } 
    }
    $row = array_pad($row, 8, null);
    print_r($row);
}
```

**Update for variable maximum length of a $row array:**

```
$rows = array();
$max = 0;

while($row = fgetcsv($fp, ",")){
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        if ($row[0] == $email['PersonId']) {
            $row[] = $email['EmailAddress'];
        }
    }
    if (count($row) > $max) {
        $max = count($row);
    }
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $row = array_pad($row, $max, null);
    print_r($row);
}
```

The while loop loops over the CSV file and finds all the e-mail addresses for PersonId and adds them to the current $row array.

Once all these are found, it counts the number of elements in the $row array. If this number is larger than the number currently stored in the $max variable, the $max variable is updated with the new number.

When the while loop has ended, $max contains the maximum number of elements a $row array can have.

We then need to loop over the arrays one more time to pad each array with null values to give them the same (the maximum) number of elements.

Comment: Well I’m not sure what the total number would be to pad and it will change with each CSV file. So I’d need the max I tried messing around with max($row) too but couldnt get that working either.